# Можно ли добавить к Bundle изменения?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-bundle

Добавляю в одном фрагменте в Bundle args переменную следующим образом:

```
args.putStringArrayList(Fragment.DOING, MyArray)
```

В другом фрагменте делаю то же самое и в итоге в Bundle прошлая запись затирается в пользу новой.
Можно ли ДОБАВИТЬ к элементу Bundle что-то,а не перезаписывать его каждый раз.
Поясню на примере: если MyArray - собственно Array, то я хочу с помощью Bundle добавлять в него элементы а не каждый раз перезаписывать заново по ключу RestartFragment.DOING. Ну и вариант с разными ключами тоже отпадает т.к. фрагментов не мало

Comment: Список списков? `args.getExtras().getStringArrayList(Fragment.DOING).add(MyArray);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bundle` не то место где нужно что-то хранить, а тем более в больших объемах.

Поэтому ответ на ваш вопрос: **Нет, нельзя.**

Вы можете либо генерировать всякий раз новый ключ, либо передавать списки данных, что тоже нехорошо.

Если вам необходимо что-то хранить в течении долгого времени и изменять используйте хранилища данных (репозитории в кэше, базы данных, `ViewModel`-и или `Presenter`-ы и т.д.).

`Bundle` это способ передать какие-то простые данные вроде ключей или строк.